# Why IBT_2 motor driver is more powerfull with Arduino then with Stm32

Tags: arduino, stm32

The question is why in DIY Force Feedback applications for PC racing simulators, the FFB is more powerfull with Arduino then with STM32. Can it be due to the diffrent logic level that goes from them. 5v Arduino and, 3.3 STM32. The IBT_2 logic levels are 3.3-5v. I believe that hardly, but still. The IBT_2 driver operating voltage is 5 volts. Arduino provide 5 volts, and stm 32 about 4.3v from it's 5volts pins. But IBT_2 also work on it. Can it be due to the fact that arduino has more "amps" in it's logic. Or is it due to the diffrent software used, or diffrent power provided from these two controllers. Or what else can be out there?) Thanks!

Comment: "*FFB is more powerful with Arduino then with STM32*" This is a false generalization, unless you are referring to specific projects but you have not stated any.

Comment: Why false? I will provide a link on a youtube channel with a builded base with my1025 motor, will it change anything? I tried bouth, of controllers. And with stm the motor draws less current. Stated not only by me, if you want so) 
So i must be wrong. The bts chips vgs on on 3 volts should be less, then with 5volts. That why all is so really then. But if you have other explanations that will be very helpful.

Comment: False because there's no general reason for that to be the case and you haven't provided specific examples so I can only assume you are asking about the general case. Either that or you have not made it clear what you are really asking. Provide us context, we aren't mind readers so lay out everything for us before asking your question. You start asking about Arduino and STM32 but then start talking about a BTS_2.

Comment: Gosh))) the motor has less torque then with stm32. There is Mmos software for stm, and emc, or a wheelconfig no matter, for arduino Leonardo. So you stated that logic levels are not the case?

Comment: First you said the Arduino was more powerful, but just now you said the STM32 was more powerful...Logic levels do not determine how "powerful" something is as long as the are compatible. It just determines whether it works or not. But I still do not know what you are trying to ask since you keep delivering it in small pieces and seem to assume I know what you have in front of you.

Comment: Show me pls where I said more powerfull with Stm?

Comment: Have got the links on the build     https://www.xsimulator.net/community/threads/diy-mosfet-h-bridge-driver.13286/page-2#post-181516

Comment: https://www.xsimulator.net/community/threads/arduino-leonardo-sim-wheel.12741/page-3#post-192320

Comment: "*the motor has less torque then with stm32*" means that the STM32 is more powerful.

Comment: it means all the same actually, and not vice verse, don't you find it?

Comment: No, you cannot reverse it. "I am happier with a mansion than with an apartment".

Comment: Okay, so what you are really saying is that you have controlled the BTS_2 using both an Arduino and an STM32. But the the motor seems to be respond more powerfully with an Arduino and you want to know why? That would not be logic levels. It would be the software.

Comment: You need to learn to ask clearer and better questions. Your problem is you assume we know what you have in front of you. It is obvious to you what you have because it is your project and you have it in front of you. We know nothing about your project and you can't expect us to assume things. In your post you start asking talking about the Arduino and STM32. Then you suddenly start talking about a BTS_2 expecting that we would assume that you tried controlling the BTS_2 with both the Arduino and the STM32.

Comment: Hmm. good point. All that soft has gain level. EMC that is with arduino has a constant force slider on it also. MMOS not. So without applied Constant force, the EMC is like MMOS. But if the constant is 100%, it really outpowers the MMOS. How that can be implemented in pwm controll?  I have no intention to think out anything out here. )

Comment: Please stop using very project specific terms like EMC and MMOS without saying what they are first. They are vague enough that google isn't telling me what they actually are. But the BTS_2 already accepts PWM signals. I assume both microcontrollers are already using PWM to drive the BTS_2. So you probably have to modify the software.

Comment: The thing is we do not have the codes, the soft are locked as you can guess ofcourse. And bad I don't have oscilloscope to look up the pwm signals. What they are with bouth of the programs. I applogise if the question was not clear. So the code then. Cool.

Comment: If they were not using PWM, then the motor would not be variable speed/force. It would be 100% or 0%, which should be fairly obvious if you see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks pal!) That was helpfull.